# Dictionary within a function passing values to another function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am having an issue with my code. I am relatively new at coding. My issue is that I am trying to take the dictionary SeatingOrder populated in the Waitlist.GuestList function and then pass those values, if there are any, to the Staff function so that I can display them in a drop-down and modify them. I can't seem to find a way to do it and any help or even a point in the right direction would be helpful.

```
import math
from tkinter import *
import time

#initializes time based on system time
count= int(0)
t= time.localtime()
current_Time = float(time.strftime("%H%M%S", t))
SeatingOrder = {''}

root=Tk()
root.title("Main Screen")
root.geometry("1920x1080")


def WaitList():
    #tnikter screen setup
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Seating List")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")

    #creates label and entry box
    PartyName = Entry(root)
    PartyName.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(root,text="Enter the party name: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    #creates label and entry box
    PartySize = Entry(root)
    PartySize.grid(row=0, column=3)
    Label(root, text="How many are in your party? ").grid(row=0, column=2)

    #creates a dictionary with an array inside of it so information can be search by the key value
    SeatingOrder = {PartyName : [PartySize, current_Time]}

    #defintion to populate array
    def GuestList(): 
        x = str(PartyName.get())
        y = int(PartySize.get())
        SeatingOrder = {x : [y, current_Time]}
        #Prints statement and displays the result
        Label(root, text="Your spot has been saved!").grid(row=3, column=1)
        Label(root, text=SeatingOrder).grid(row=3, column=2)      

    #creates a button the runs the command.
    Button(root, text="Save", command=GuestList).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(root, text="x", command=root.destroy).grid(row=1, column=10)
    root.mainloop()
    

    return SeatingOrder


def Staff():
    Dictionary = WaitList()
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Administration")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    def show():
        Label(root, Text=clicked.get()).grid(row=1, column=1)
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set("Please select a party")

    SeatingDropDown = OptionMenu(root, clicked, )
    SeatingDropDown.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Button(root, text="select", command=show).grid(row=0, column=2)

    Button(root, text="x", command=root.destroy).grid(row=1, column=10)
    exit

Button(root, text="Waitlist", command=WaitList).grid(row=5, column=1)
Button(root, text="Staff", command=Staff).grid(row=5, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This would be an appropriate use of a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just one point is that in this code you have set up a root main screen window and for each function you have set up a new root window (note that Staff window has no mainloop call and so wouldn't have an event loop)

But I would scrap all that. The usual way with tkinter is to have a root (Main screen) and all subsequent windows are made tkinter.Toplevel with the root as master. Skeleton example for just this point:

```
import tkinter as tk
root - tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080+0+0')     # geometry is 'widthxheight+x+y'
WaitListwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
WaitListwindow.pack()
WaitListwindow.place(x=10,y=10)    #place values are now relative to the root geometry
Staffwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
Staffwindow.pack()
Staffwindow.place(x=70,y=10)       
root.mainloop()
```

now root is the parent\master and WaitListWindow and StaffWindow are the children. Note that I use pack and place but grid applies just as well with the appropriate parameters.

You can then place the buttons and entry as children of the appropraite window, eg

```
staffselectb = tk.Button(Staffwindow)
staffselectb.pack()
staffselectb.place(x=5,y=5)            # this button is now relative to Staffwindow placement
                                       #so that x and y are inside Staffwindow at (5,5)
```

With the root.mainloop() you can now bind events to a widget, eg to retrieve the Entry widget contents.

There is more but I just wanted to concentrate on this point.